# Add 1 day every x rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add 1 day every 3 rows.

The date

```
start_date = "01/02/21"

date_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%d/%m/%y")
end_date = date_1 + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
df_4["date"] = end_date
```

The wanted output

```
A   date
1   01/02/21
2   01/02/21
3   01/02/21
4   02/02/21 # add 1 day
5   02/02/21
6   02/02/21
7   03/02/21 # add 1 day
8   03/02/21
9   03/02/21
10  04/02/21 # add 1 day
11  04/02/21
12  04/02/21
...
```

Now it adds 1 day to all rows and not one more day every 3 rows

Comment: How looks input data?

Comment: df_4 has multiple columns and multiple rows. I just want to add a date for each rows

Comment: it means add 1 day row? Or add 1 day for increement day?

Comment: increement day I guess. Add one day from the three previous one rows.

Comment: Are you sure? So input data sample has 12 rows?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a good english speaker. Let me clarify. Let's say the starting date is 01/01/2021. The three first row will have 01/01/2021 as a date. Then the three next rows will have + 1 day = 02/01/2021, then the three next rows will have + 1 day = 03/01/2021 etc.... (the input data has thousands of rows). So it can go to many future years (and more)

Comment: So inout is empty column? And input is `01/01/2021` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need each 3 values starting by `start_date` add timedeltas days generated by `np.arange` with length of DataFrame what is faster like loop solutions:

```
start_date = "01/02/21"

date_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%d/%m/%y")
df["date"] = date_1 + pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(len(df)) // 3, unit='d')


print (df)
     A       date Note
0    1 2021-02-01  NaN
1    2 2021-02-01  NaN
2    3 2021-02-01  NaN
3    4 2021-02-02  add
4    5 2021-02-02  NaN
5    6 2021-02-02  NaN
6    7 2021-02-03   ad
7    8 2021-02-03  NaN
8    9 2021-02-03  NaN
9   10 2021-02-04  add
10  11 2021-02-04  NaN
11  12 2021-02-04  NaN
```

**Details**:

```
print (np.arange(len(df)) // 3)
[0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]

print (pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(len(df)) // 3, unit='d'))
TimedeltaIndex(['0 days', '0 days', '0 days', '1 days', '1 days', '1 days',
                '2 days', '2 days', '2 days', '3 days', '3 days', '3 days'],
               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet below will increment the date by one day in the row after every 3 rows (as specified by the `add_every_x_rows`)

```
df['Date'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x), "%d/%m/%y").date() for x in df['Date']]

add_every_x_rows = 3

day_counter = 0
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    day_counter+=1
    if (day_counter == add_every_x_rows +1):
        df.at[i,'Date'] = row['Date'] + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        day_counter = 1
```

If you later change the value of `add_every_x_rows` to 4, it will start incrementing the date by one day at every four rows.

Comment: Thank you for your help. the accepted answer is an easier way to do it for me. But thanks anyway

Comment: Maybe you can avoid `iterrows`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316